# ROS virtual box streaming on htc vive on windows

Tags: ros, virtual-reality, oculus, htc-vive

my current situation is that I need to run a simulation on htc vive using ROS. For now I have connected ROS and v-rep on virtual box, ubuntu. I have connected htc vive on windows and setted it up with steam vr. I would like to set it up so that I could stream simulation through virtual box using ROS on htc vive which is on windows.

I know that I need to write a script for that, ROS using TCP so I can connect vive which is on windows, but I am also interested if someone can explain me more about that, or someone has better solution for running a simulation on vive using ROS since I haven't done something like that before? Or is it simpler to use oculus rift with dual boot and put ROS there?

Answer (score 0):

as no one has answered you might guess there is a bigger gap....you would have to visualize your ros worl. Also you need a two way comminication...thought you have to study some more technolgies and come with a problem